# Asynchronous DNS look-ups using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm trying to write a script in NodeJS to asynchronously do many DNS look-ups (to check blacklists on an IP address)

Here is my current attempt:

```
const dns = require('dns');

RBLs = [
    'b.barracudacentral.org',
    'cbl.abuseat.org',
    'http.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
    'misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
    'socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
    'web.dnsbl.sorbs.net',
];

var testIP = "IP.ADDRESS";

console.time("exetime");
var RBLResults = {};

var RBLCallback = function(err, result, RBL){
  if(typeof result !== "undefined" && result.length > 0){
    console.log("LISTED on " + RBL);
  }else{
    console.log(" Not listed on " + RBL);
  }
};

RBLs.forEach(function(RBL){
  dns.lookup(testIP + '.' + RBL, function(err, result){
    RBLCallback(err,result,RBL);
  });
});
```

As far as I understand, this should asynchronously start all the DNS lookups. However, the longer the list gets, the more clear it is that the DNS requests are not happening at the same time. (I'm trying to check 106 blacklists at once.)

Am I hitting some limitation with how many DNS lookups I can do at once? The order that the results comes in almost never changes, so it seems like they are not happening asynchronously. The last one in the list always takes much much longer to come in than the first.

The amount of time it takes to complete is really variable, going from 10 seconds to 100+ seconds.

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean to say "asynchronous", not "synchronous" in your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Well, your DNS requests will all start at some local DNS server and then be fanned out from there to other DNS servers.  What is your local DNS server configured to be?  Is it your local home router?  What are you expecting the result to be that you aren't seeing?

Comment: `dns.lookup()` eventually ends up calling native code [`uv_getaddrinfo()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/cares_wrap.cc#L2008) so if you really wanted to see how the implementation works on your particular platform, you'd have to look into the lib uv library for your platform.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, so it sounds like the local DNS server needs to be configured as well to handle asynchronous lookups as well? if that is possible? If that's what needs to happen, that sounds like a whole new question. I'm using 4 different name servers at the dataCenter, but they are not doing the lookups very fast...

Comment: What result are you expecting that you are not seeing?

Comment: Well, I thought that if I did asynchronous DNS lookups to different hosts, the results would come back all at once (or very close together). Instead, I'm getting results from one at a time, and the last one on the list comes in much later than the first one. There are sometimes seconds between responses, when there should still be 50 or so DNS lookups happening. It can take over 100 seconds.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to ask "why is it so slow to get DNS results for 106 hosts"?  Then, give the metrics you've measured and what range of time you would expect it to be.  Questions work a lot better if you state the actual top level problem to be addressed and exactly what you observed to be happening rather than assuming you know it's a problem with asynchronous behavior.  This lets people help you with the overall problem much better.

Comment: Also, please thoroughly describe your hosting environment where you are running this.  For example, the local DNS server could be rate limiting you when firing off lots of requests at once (purposely slowing down your requests in order to make sure good service is not denied to other tenants).

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty novice when it comes to DNS stuff. Looks like I have control over the local DNS servers we're using, so I'll probably be able to locate the issue there. This is most likely a rate limiting problem. Anyway, it seems this question probably didn't actually have much relevant content to what the actual problem was, so I'll probably delete it in a minute or so. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue in the nodeJS documentation for `dns`:

> Though the call to dns.lookup() will be asynchronous from JavaScript's
>   perspective, it is implemented as a synchronous call to getaddrinfo(3)
>   that runs on libuv's threadpool. This can have surprising negative
>   performance implications for some applications, see the
>   UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE documentation for more information.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations

So from the Javascript side of things, it did appear to be working asynchronously, but it actually wasn't.

To make the DNS look ups happen asynchronously, I just replaced `dns.lookup` with `dns.resolve()`.

I instantly started getting results that actually looked asynchronous. (results started actually coming back in different orders than the look ups were starting in)